# Reading from a File Based on String Input

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert a Perl program over to Python.

What I would like to have happen is for the input to be read, and then the matching output comes out from the file based on the string.

So far, this is what I've tried (for this particular function):

```
def SunSign():

    print ("\n\nYou want to know more about your Sun Sign!\n")
    print ("Your sun sign is your core identity and probably the sign that you are most familiar with as it is your zodiac!\n\n")

    sun = input("What is your Sun Sign?\n")

    with open("sunsigns.txt", "r") as file:

        content = file.read()

        if sun in content:
            print(sun)

    Restart()
```

I realize that the variable I have printing is not what I need. That's the part I need assistance on figuring out. If I switch out sun with content, it will print out the whole file.

Comment: What part of the file do you want to print? The line that matches `sun`? Then loop over the lines and test `if sun in line:` and then print that line.

Comment: Your question isn't clear, what does "file based on the string" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go through the file line by line, then print the line that contains the sign you're looking for:

```
with open('sunsigns.txt','r') as f:
   for line in f:       
       if sun in line:
          print(line)
```